# JQuery within an Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

why this will work

```
$("body").on("click",".open_popup",function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $("#form1").show(); 

    })
```

but the same code inside an object,like so:

```
var popUpFormulario = {

              openWith: function () {
        self=this;

        $("body").on("click",".open_popup",function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            $("#"+self.id+"").show();   

        })
    }
```

and then calling the function like this

```
popUpFormulario.openWith()
```

just wont ? i don't get it. can someone explain it to me ? thanks in advance

Comment: where is no `id` property for `popUpFormulario ` so `$("#"+self.id+"")` will give `$("#undefined")` which does not exists

Comment: why do you want to do this, what do you expect `self.id` to be

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be this line:  `$("#"+self.id+"").show();` (which doesn't need the last "", so `$("#"+self.id).show()`, but that's not the issue)

`self` is `this` which is the `openWith` function, which obviously does not have a DOM element ID.